# DataFrame: Get the mean of two rows to a set it to a row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like,

```
             ds             value
====================================
1 2023-07-01 17:00:00        100
2 2023-07-01 18:00:00         0
3 2023-07-01 19:00:00        300
```

I want to set the mean of 1st and 3rd rows value into the 2nd row like this

```
             ds             value
====================================
1 2023-07-01 17:00:00       100
2 2023-07-01 18:00:00       150
3 2023-07-01 19:00:00       200
```

And some times it may be more that one rows which will be having **0**, is there a way to handle that dynamically.

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with [`Series.interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html):

```
df['value'] = df['value'].replace(0, np.nan).interpolate()
```